# How do I align printed columns of vectors with sprintf (R)

Tags: c, r, formatting

Let’s say I have 3 vectors in R:

```
x <- c("xskdlfl", "  y", "lkjsf")
y <- c(22.5, 6, 7.0)
z <- c("slk","llkjdf", "xx")
```

I would like to produce a formatted tabular output with the right-most character aligned like so in all columns except the first:

```
xskdlfl        y     lkjsf
22.5         5.6       7.0
slk       llkjdf        xx
```

I cannot figure out how to do this with sprintf without a lot of messy programming in R. Is there a straightforward way to do this in R using sprintf? Using ‘format?’ I’d appreciate a link to a good sprintf tutorial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no clue about in R, but in C you can specify the width of each field, right or left justification and any leading filler using the printf family.

Comment: Is this going in a document? Or are you just talking about console output?

Comment: Also, `sprintf` will apply the same formatting to everything in the vector given to it. Since your formatting is column-dependent it would make more sense to use column vectors than row vectors

Comment: With regard to your request for `sprintf` tutorials, `example(sprintf)` has a ton of useful examples

Comment: Suggestion abt column data very good idea I overlooked. Need to read more about printf to see how to set column formats. Have looked at many tutorials and most have toy examples that don’t deal with more complex data structures. Help for sprintf didn’t lead me to answer, but that’s prob. just me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x <- c("xskdlfl", "  y", "lkjsf")
y <- c(22.5, 6, 7.0)
z <- c("slk","llkjdf", "xx")

(dat <- setNames(data.frame(rbind(x, y, z)), c('x','y','z')))

#         x      y     z
# x xskdlfl      y lkjsf
# y    22.5      6     7
# z     slk llkjdf    xx

with(dat, data.frame(x = sprintf(paste0('%-', max(nchar(x)), 's'), x), y, z))

#         x      y     z
# 1 xskdlfl      y lkjsf
# 2 22.5         6     7
# 3 slk     llkjdf    xx
```

You can add padding to the left or right of the string like so:

```
sprintf('%7s', z)
# [1] "    slk" " llkjdf" "     xx"

sprintf('%-7s', z)
# [1] "slk    " "llkjdf " "xx     "
```

and it is just a matter of figuring out how much, 7 in this case, based off the number of characters `nchar` of the strings

Comment: To match OP, you'll need a transpose in there.

Comment: gotcha. I was staring forever trying to figure out where the 5.6 came from and the order

Comment: One of best coverages of (s)printf I found: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=20519

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly pretty, but effective:

```
mat = rbind(x, y, z)

for (i in 1:ncol(mat)) {
    mat[, i] = format(mat[, i], justify = ifelse(i == 1, "left", "right"))
}

mat
#   [,1]      [,2]     [,3]   
# x "xskdlfl" "     y" "lkjsf"
# y "22.5   " "     6" "    7"
# z "slk    " "llkjdf" "   xx"

row.names(mat) = NULL
noquote(mat)
#      [,1]    [,2]   [,3] 
# [1,] xskdlfl      y lkjsf
# [2,] 22.5         6     7
# [3,] slk     llkjdf    xx
```

If you define your vectors as columns with uniform within-column formatting rather than rows with within-row differences, it gets a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use sprintf like in C, this way:

```
int main(){
    char a[] = "azerty";
    char b[] = "qsdfghjkl";
    char c[] = "wxcvbn,;:!";
    printf ("%-20s\t%20s\t%20s\n", a, b, c);
    printf ("%-20s\t%20s\t%20s\n", b, c, a);
    printf ("%-20s\t%20s\t%20s\n", c, a, b);
    return 0;
}
```